How to disable warnings about unused variables in settings vscode?
How to disable warnings about unused variables in settings vscode? I looked for an answer on the Internet, but I couldn’t find it, I tried to disable it myself, but nothing worked. I don’t want to constantly write “@SuppressWarnings(“unused”)” to disable them, I need to change something in the global settings.
Attempts to change something, as was the case with the C language, turned out to be even for Java

depends on the language support extension probably. what language support extension are you using? also, it's not clear to me what your current last sentence means. please edit to clarify.
